# Composite or just square the Function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Given function $=
 h(x)=\frac{3-x}2$ ,
Find composite function $h^2$

Did the question mean, taking $\frac{3-x}2$ and just squaring it?
Or take $h(h(x))$ ?

Comment: The notation means $h(h(x))$.  For squaring, you would write $h(x) \cdot h(x)$.

Comment: If you wanted to square it, we would write $h(x)\cdot h(x)$ or $[h(x)]^2$. Sometimes, we will write a superscript *before* the left parenthesis to denote composition. For instance, $h^1 (x) = h(x), h^2(x) = h(h(x)), h^3(x) = h(h(h(x))), etc.$ If you are familiar with calculus, this notation will sometimes mean first, second, and third derivatives of $h$, respectively. In this question, though, they mean $h(h(x))$.

Comment: Thanks very much @Luna145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three notations:
$$f(x)^n=\Big(f(x)\Big)^n$$
$$f^n(x)=\underbrace{f(f(\cdots(x)\cdots)}_{n\textrm{ times}}$$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\dfrac{\textrm d^n}{\textrm dx^n}f(x)$$
In your case, it is the second one being used.

(For historical reasons, the trigonometric functions follow a different notation, comment if you want to know about it as well!)

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Oh ok, got it, thanks !

Comment: @Mahyesh: On MathSE, if an answer to your question helps you, you must mark one of the answers that helped you as "accepted". [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/842234) link explains how it works.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know !!

Answer (score 0):

For an Algebraic structure $(G,*)$ ( $G$ is the set and $*$ is a binary operation on $G$) we often use the notation $a^n$ for $a\in G$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to denote
$$a^1=a$$
and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 2$
$$a^n=a^{n-1}*a$$
Since here the operation is composition, $h\circ h=h^2$, which mean $h^2(x)=h(h(x))$ for all $x$ in the domain of $h$.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the Algebraic structure is, (G,∗) ? -i've never heard of it...

Comment: Haven't you learn Group Theory ?

Comment: No, I haven't learnt it yet, but i'll look into it thanks!